# How do I remove Spring Security's requirement of signing in with a username and password before I access my Spring Application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I set up a new Spring Boot Application and for some reason every time I start/restart the server the following window appears.

[image: Screenshot of login page]

I'm provided with the password in the console e.g. `Using generated security password: 1ecb3270-f767-4142-a59c-603ffd7eaec5`, so logging into the application isn't an issue however it's becoming a bit of a nuisance. I've tried to find a way to remove this, but I've had no joy. Thank you!

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.0

Comment: Do you want do disable security at all?

Comment: Well I intend to include log in functionality in the Application (as in a user can log in to an online bookstore) which I believe requires Spring Security? Is this correct?

Comment: So this means I have to keep the login mentioned in the question and log in every time I use start/restart the server?

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot protects all URLs by default.

Comment: Why is it annoying? You could change the default configuration, for example make `/` unprotected?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread you, So by configuring the WebSecurityConfig file, I can bypass this?

Comment: Sure, you can use a custom security configuration.